# LibGDX can't access internal image resources

Tags: java, android, oop, android-studio, libgdx

I clearly stored my "background.png" in the assets folder under android.
I also checked that it was there in Finder.

I am working with Android Studio.

However, upon trying to access the image:

```
public Background() {
    textureRegion = new TextureRegion(new Texture("background.png"));
    textureRegionBounds1 = new Rectangle(0 - Constants.APP_WIDTH / 2, 0, Constants.APP_WIDTH, Constants.APP_HEIGHT);
    textureRegionBounds2 = new Rectangle(Constants.APP_WIDTH / 2, 0, Constants.APP_WIDTH, Constants.APP_HEIGHT);
}
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: background.png
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GLTexture.createTextureData(GLTexture.java:185)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:103)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:95)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:91)
at com.com.waylonhuang.game.actors.Background.<init>(Background.java:21)
at com.com.waylonhuang.game.stages.GameStage.setUpBackground(GameStage.java:66)
at com.com.waylonhuang.game.stages.GameStage.setUpWorld(GameStage.java:59)
at com.com.waylonhuang.game.stages.GameStage.<init>(GameStage.java:51)
at com.mygdx.game.GameScreen.<init>(GameScreen.java:16)
at com.mygdx.game.DrifterGame.create(DrifterGame.java:11)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:137)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: background.png (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
    ... 13 more......
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
Also, my current path for the Desktop launcher for the Working Directory is : AndroidStudioProjects/libGDXGame

However, upon changing it to: AndroidStudioProjects/libGDXGame/android/assets

I get a new error like such:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.com.waylonhuang.game.stages.GameStage.draw(GameStage.java:134)
at com.mygdx.game.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:25)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:208)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this:

```
textureRegion = new TextureRegion(new Texture(
                Gdx.files.internal("background.png")));
```

if it does not work review, case sensitive, of the file name.

**Edit:** look that is a copy of the file, not a link, once he happened to someone so wrong

Comment: Hi, I tried this just now, and it still does not work. The characters are all lower case in my file name so there's no mistake there. Also, I made sure that the file type was .png as shown..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't load assets in a constructor directly because Gdx.files is null. Either load the assets outside of the constructor or use the `AssetsManager`.