# Error reading file: uiskin.json - only on Android

Tags: android, json, libgdx

I have been using the default uiskin pack for a menu screen:

[GitHub: libgdx/test/gdx-tests-android/assets/data](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data)

- uiskin.atlas
- uiskin.json
- uiskin.png
- default.png
- default.fnt

This works on Desktop.  However on Android, I get this `SerializationException`:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 3432
Process: com.ttocsneb.matrix.android, PID: 1506
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file:
skins/uiskin.json
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:97)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:82)
at com.ttocsneb.matrix.screen.MenuScreen.show(MenuScreen.java.35)
...
```

The error comes from the initialization of the skin:

```
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"), new  TextureAtlas("uiskin.atlas"));
```

Comment: look at my answer to this question, in part edit, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141547/libgdx-cant-access-internal-image-resources/28141644#28141644  maybe help  you

Comment: Thanks @AngelAngel within the uiskin.json `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } },` _default.fnt_ had a different capitalization from the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the string to the path directly. Try to pass the string through Gdx.files.internal().

```
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"), new  TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.atlas")));
```